# Unable to ping to Ubuntu server

Tags: networking, server, ssh, ip, putty

I want to connect my Windows device to a Ubuntu device by using Putty. Both devices are on the campus network, the only difference is the Ubuntu device is connected to the router which is also connected to the campus network, but Windows device is using a campus wifi. I have the IP address for the Ubuntu device as well as the port#, I also checked the SSH is running on the Ubuntu device too and no firewall on. But I can not ping to the Ubuntu device from my Windows device. Why is that?

Comment: You possibly are trying to ping the external IP that your server is connected to and your university's router is not sending that ping to your Ubuntu server.

Comment: Do you know how can I make the router send the ping to my Ubuntu server? or do you know how can I directly ping to my Ubuntu server? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say "router", I'm going to assume that you are using a common consumer grade residential gateway/wireless access point "router". Commercial grade routers would require additional configuration to get routing itself to work, such as setting up routing protocols or static routes. I suspect this isn't the problem you have.

If the Ubuntu device is behind a router, the router is probably acting as a firewall for the devices behind it, such as the Ubuntu device. You may need to configure the firewall to allow traffic destined for the Ubuntu system to pass.

The router is probably also operating as a NAT device, and may need to be configured to translate connections to the router's IP address to the IP addresses of devices behind the router/NAT. In this scenario, the Ubuntu device is actually on a separate LAN than the rest of the campus since it's behind it's own router, so the Windows computer wouldn't be able to connect to the Ubuntu device's IP address at all, but could ping the router's IP address.

Consumer grade routers commonly use Port Address Translation, which is where you can configure the router to forward connections to port 22 (for SSH) on the router's IP address to a particular port (such as 22) on a particular device's IP (such as the Ubuntu system) behind the NAT device. The way this works is the Windows computer would actually try to connect to the IP address of the NAT device (router), but the NAT device would forward those connections to the Ubuntu device using the IP address and port specified in the configuration.

It's also possible that your campus is preventing the connections directly, which you can't do much about.

You might have an easier time if you connect the Ubuntu device to a simple switch or a wireless access point instead of a wireless router so that it would still be on the same LAN as the rest of the campus.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried to connect to the same router with my Windows device and Ubuntu device, I can successfully connected to the Ubuntu device. But the problem is I need to remote control my Ubuntu device, which means the Windows device can not connected to the same router as Ubuntu device. So as you said, I can I find out the IP address of the router(which connected to the campus network)? and how to configure the router to forward connections to port 22? Thanks

Comment: That makes sense. What you need to do to set up port forwarding on the router to forward connections to a particular port on the router's ip (such as port 22) to port 22 on the Ubuntu server. 

How to do this depends entirely on the type of router you have. Just Google "port forwarding" and the model of your router for instructions.

Once that is complete, you connect to port 22 on the router ip address, and the router will forward the connection to the Ubuntu server.